# What time interval when async mode is bad?

Tags: asynchronous, concurrency, cpu

I remember that I read that if task is complete faster than `n` msecs it's should not run as async. But I can't find any articles or docs where this interval is described.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on concrete use case. One corner case is when the main thread needs the result of the (possibly) async function and can do nothing without that result. Then the function should never be run as async. On the opposite side, if the main thread does not need the result of async function, then any function which executes longer than the time to launch async execution (several microseconds), should be run in async mode.